# Eclipse: Insert Type Javadoc in New Classes Automatically

Tags: eclipse, templates

I'm using Eclipse Neon. I have updated Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates -> Comments -> Types to include a copyright notice in the class javadoc:

```
/**
 * @author My Company ${year} 
 *
 * ${tags}
 */
```

Under Code Templates -> Code -> New Java files it has:

```
${filecomment}
${package_declaration}

${typecomment}
${type_declaration}
```

However, when I create a new Java class via the New wizard (either right click the package or from the File -> New menu, it doesn't insert the class javadoc.

Can I set Eclipse to add this when a new class is created?

Comment: It does this for me. Make sure you have the 'Generate comments' check box selected near the bottom of the New Class dialog.

Comment: @greg-449 Do you know if there's a way to have that box checked by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a 'Generate comments' check box on the New Class dialog that controls if the comments are added.

The default for this check box come from the 'Java > Code Style > Code Templates' preference page - the 'Automatically add comments to new methods and types' check box at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Another way :
You can update "Code Templates -> Code -> New Java Files"  as below:

```
${filecomment}
${package_declaration}

${typecomment}

/**
 * @author My Company ${year} 
 *
 * ${tags}
 */
${type_declaration}
```

With this we don't need to check 'Generate comments' check box on the New Class dialog